# Group by and values_counts

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

My df looks like that

```
session_id page_type
10001_0    a
10001_0    b
10001_0    b
10001_0    b
10001_0    c
10001_0    c
10002_0    a
10002_0    a
10002_0    b
10002_0    b
10002_0    c
10002_0    c
```

I want to groupby by 'session_id' and counts the values('a','b','c') 
As:

```
session_id count_page_type
10001_0 {a:1,b:3,c:2}
10002_0 {a:2,b:2,c:2}
```

I don't care about the type in 'count_page_type' column 
it can be list as well.
The aggregation is on multiple columns,

```
agg_dict = ({'uid':'first',
             'request_id':'unique',
             'sso_id':'first',
             'article_id' :['first','last','nunique'],
             'event_time':['min','max'],
             'session_duration':'sum',
             'anonymous_id':['first','nunique'],
             'platform':['first','nunique'],
             'brand':['first','last','nunique'],
             'user_type':['first','last'],
             'page_type':'value_counts'})
df.groupby('session_id').agg(agg_dict)
```

Now i am getting error

```
ValueError: cannot insert page_type, already exists
```

any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value_counts` returns rather a `pd.Series` rather than just a row,  try doing something like :

```py
df.groupby('session_id').agg({'page_type': lambda x : x.value_counts().to_dict()})
```